# mysql find unique differences in two tables

Tags: mysql

I have a problem figuring out the difference between two tables.

First of all I want to join the two tables, as I want to exclude entries like step 6 and step 11. I only need to check for a match on the field: step

Then I am trying to figure out which steps that don't have a match on the option field. Example step 5 has a match with option 16. Then step 5 needs to be removed somehow and the problem is step 5, option 15 - which I can't really "get rid of".

```
Table 1:  
--------------
Fields: STEP, OPTION

 - 5, 16
 - 10, 15
 - 11, 31
 - 12, 14

Table 2:
----------
Fields: STEP, OPTION

 - 5, 15
 - 5, 16
 - 6, 7
 - 12, 13
```

Basically the result I am looking for is step 12, option 13.

Guess it would be somewhere along the lines of:

SELECT * FROM table1 AS T1 INNER JOIN table2 AS T2 ON T1.step=T2.step

And then with the result of that, you would have to do something like (I know it is not correct SQL, but I don't know how to do it):

SELECT step FROM above_result WHERE (T1.step=T2.step AND T1.option=T2.option) == HAVING COUNT 0

As step 5 would then have count 1 and step 12 count 0.

I have tried various grouping, counting, joining - but has not yet been able to crack it.

I hope it is more clear now

Comment: What makes 12 unique but not 6, 11 or 10?

Comment: Join the two tables, group by both Step and Option, find groups having a count of 1?

Comment: what is the query you've tried ?

Comment: Just updated the question - hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint from gunr2171 - the solution that helps me is the folllowing query:

> SELECT MP.step_id, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table2 WHERE
>   option_id=CP.option_id AND step_id=CP.step_id) counter FROM table2 AS
>   MP INNER JOIN table1 AS CP ON CP.step_id=MP.step_id HAVING counter = 0

I am not sure it is the fastest solution, but it solves my problem - which were to find the "unique" step, with match on step, but not option - between two tables.